In React if a render is discarded, are the useEffects still run (and cleaned up?)
I'm trying to wrap my mind around the semantics of discarded renders which I understand can happen in concurrent mode.
I would expect that if a render is discarded then none of the useEffect()s are called. Firstly, because useEffects() should run after the commit and well at commit the render is not being discarded by definition.
Is this correct, or do useEffect()s run on discarded renders as well?

useEffect runs after commit. If there is no commit, it wont run

It may or may not be the case, but you shouldn't rely on this behaviour as whatever it does now might change in future versions of React.
The docs are vague on purpose (https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect, note the "generally" and "may"):


If your Effect wasn’t caused by an interaction (like a click), React will generally let the browser paint the updated screen first before running your Effect.
If your Effect is caused by an interaction (like a click), React may run your Effect before the browser paints the updated screen.


But generally speaking, it should not matter, because you should design your effects with a cleanup function, in a way that it doesn't make a difference whether it runs or not (as long as it gets cleaned up). Effects are used for synchronizing with external systems, not for irreversible side effects.

Digging further, there is some inconsistency in that the React docs themselves allude to using useEffect() as a "do something if some prop or state changes" i.e. an irreversible one-off side effect. Eg: https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#reading-latest-props-and-state-with-effect-events. This example makes sense (and I'm talking about the useEffect part not the experimental useEventEffect part) only if the effect is triggered exactly once every time the url prop changes. How would you handle that if useEffect may trigger multiple times per prop change in concurrent mode?

Another example of the docs suggesting that discarded renders don't trigger useEffects is the behavior of strict mode. In strict mode components re-render and extra time - but that just results in the pure function parts of the component to be called twice, not the useEffect. (useEffect does get called twice is strict mode, but that is from mount-umount-remount, not from the double render).

A case for discarded renders have been documented here Adjusting some state when a prop changes
That case is about adjusting some state with respect to some props.
The most notable code over there is that the component changes the state during its own render. And the documentation says that, under the event of changing the state during a render, React will throw-away the JSX it returned, and will trigger another render.
Now the question is that -  what about the useEffect in a discarded render.
The answer is that the useEffect of a discarded render will also be
discarded.
This answer has been demoed through the below sample code. Like the example in the documentation, the below sample code also adjusts a state based on a props. Now please also look at the console logs below it has generated during the initial render.
Console logs during the initial render
JSX with adjusted state :25, previous state : 25
JSX with adjusted state :25, previous state : 25
useEffect runs, adjusted state :25, previous state : 25

Please note that the repeated logs due to Strict mode has been removed for brevity. Now we can see that there are three log entries created in the initial render. As we can see in the code, the return statement as well as the useEffect code handler have been logged.
Now please take note that there are two logs pertaining to the return statement, and one log pertaining to useEffect event handler.
The first question is why do we have two logs for the return statement ?
This is because return has been executed twice. One for the discarded render and another one for the subsequent render. However there is only one log for useEffect. As we can understand that this is for the subsequent render. And it is quite clear that there is no useEffect event run for the discarded render. If it had, there should have been two logs for useEffect as well.
The reasoning for not running useEffect for a discarded render should be that : useEffect in principle is an event handler. It is almost comparable to any other event handlers like OnChange or OnClick. The only difference with respect to useEffect event is that it is invoked automatically soon after a render. The other events are invoked based on the interactions. Still the essential nature of useEffect remains the same - it is an event handler. Therefore when the JSX is discarded for a render, it needs to understand that the whole event handlers are also discarded including useEffect.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [changedState, setChangedState] = useState(new Date().getUTCSeconds());
  return (
    <>
      <Component changedProps={changedState} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setChangedState(new Date().getUTCSeconds())}>
        Change props with a random value
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
    </>
  );
}

function Component({ changedProps }) {
  const [adjustedState, setAdjustedState] = useState(changedProps);
  const [prevProps, setPrevProps] = useState(null);

  // if there is a change in the props
  if (changedProps !== prevProps) {
    // then set the component state to the new value
    // and initiate a new render.
    // Meantime keep track of the previos value as well.
    setPrevProps(adjustedState);
    setAdjustedState(changedProps);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `useEffect runs, adjusted state :${adjustedState}, previous state : ${changedProps}`
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      Adjusted State value : {adjustedState}
      {console.log(
        `JSX with adjusted state :${adjustedState}, previous state : ${changedProps}`
      )}
    </>
  );
}


Hi, Thank you very much for awarding the bounties. Thinking useEffect in line with any other events really helped me to understand the rendering process in a simple and straight manner. Like you, I was finding it very difficult to understand useEffect before getting into that thinking.

You are almost correct buddy but I will tell you how it works.
While in concurrent mode a render can be discarded if the component state changes before the render is committed to the DOM. The main purpose is optimization (makes sense right, why have unnecessary updates).
Now the use useEffect hook runs only after the component is committed to the DOM. It runs after the render cycle is completed, which means all updates to the DOM are finalized.
Since this is the case useEffect will not run for discarded renders. if a render is discarded, any effects associated with that render will not execute too.
Hope this answer helps you

Let me explain my artistic skills if you will, lol. I'll call it the
useEffect Lifecycle in Concurrent Mode diagram.
+----------------------------+
|    Initial Render Phase    |
+----------------------------+
| 1. Begin rendering         |
| 2. React creates a virtual |
|    DOM representation      |
|                            |
|  Note: `useEffect` does  |
|    NOT run here            |
+----------------------------+
          |
          v
+-----------------------------+
|    Concurrent Mode Check    |
+-----------------------------+
| React may decide to         |
| discard this render if:     |
|  - New props/state arrive   |
|  - Higher priority work     |
|    interrupts               |
+-----------------------------+
          |
          | Render is discarded
          |
          v
+-----------------------------+
|    Discarded Render Phase   |
+-----------------------------+
| React has discarded this    |
| render because it’s out of  |
| date or unnecessary.        |
|                             |
|  `useEffect` does NOT run |
|     on discarded renders.   |
|                             |
| ✔️ No cleanup is needed,    |
|     as `useEffect` was      |
|     never invoked.          |
+-----------------------------+
          |
          | If render is NOT discarded
          v
+-----------------------------+
|      Commit Phase           |
+-----------------------------+
| Render is finalized and     |
| committed to the DOM.       |
|                             |
| ▶️ `useEffect` runs here.    |
|                             |
|  If there is an existing  |
|     effect, cleanup from    |
|     the previous render     |
|     is executed first       |
|     before the new effect   |
|     runs.                   |
+-----------------------------+

In Concurrent Mode discarded renders do not trigger useEffect, therefore no cleanup is required. useEffect only runs after a render is actually committed to the DOM itself.
